# How to use Basler GigE camera pylon5 c++ libraries in Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, camera, shared-libraries, raspberry-pi2

I have tried to call pylon5 C++ libraries from separate projects, without success.

I have been searching for an answer for a while but just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I suppose my problem could be on setting the environment variables and/or library paths? (I'm beginner with Linux based things and when reading tutorials in the net I easily get confused on some obvious? things that I should? know but I don't)

I have tested that the camera itself is working with my Raspberry and I can grab images by using the example codes.

I can even modify the camera settings (exposure time etc.) and take pictures and save them to my SD-card. So the camera module is not the problem. My problem is more likely in using shared libraries in correct way.

Furthermore I have made some simple shared libraries in a hope that I could then use my Pylon camera codes from these. When I'm not including any Pylon codes in my library it works fine and returns values I want. I'm even able to add the Pylon headers there and it still compiles fine. Then again I can call my lib from another (in this case C#) code and get the return values as expected, but when trying to call any Pylon codes there (in my library) it will result in 'dllNotFoundException'.

I have placed my pylon5 codes in /opt/pylon5 as adviced in the manual that I got from the baslerweb.com
http://s.baslerweb.com/media/documents/How%20to%20build%20pylon%20applications%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi.pdf

Here is my project file (I'm using QtCreator)

```
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       -= gui
QT       += core

TARGET = baslercamera
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += BASLERCAMERA_LIBRARY

SOURCES += baslercamera.cpp \    
    Grab.cpp \
    Image.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    BaslerDLL.cpp


HEADERS += baslercamera.h\
    baslercamera_global.h \
    Image.h \
    Grab.h


unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}


#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../pylon5/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../pylon5/include

INCLUDEPATH += /opt/pylon5/include
DEPENDPATH += /opt/pylon5/include


INCLUDEPATH += /home/pi/baslercamera/
DEPENDPATH += /home/pi/baslercamera/

LIBS += "/opt/pylon5/lib" \
    -lpylonc
```

As you can see the INCLUDEPATH and LIBS variables are my weak spot. I can't figure out which libraries I should include there and how to include them correctly. Should I set some environment variables in addition to including them in my project file?

I have also tried to set some librarypaths but I don't really know what I should do there. The user manual said

```
Set the pylon environment variables:
# source ./pylon4/bin/pylon-setup-env.sh pylon4
```

and I followed this by replacing pylon4 with pylon5. I supposed that this might set the environment variables to use pylon libraries. But I'm not really sure what happens there. The pylon 5 guide says:

```
Environment Variables
=====================

From pylon 5.0 upwards, no additional environment variables are required to
run pylon-based applications.

For development, though, the compiler must know where pylon is installed.
The pylon samples use the environment variable PYLON_ROOT to find the relevant information.

For your convenience, we created the pylon-setup-env.sh script located in the 
pylon5/bin directory which can carry out the complete setup.

To setup the environment for a pylon installation in <path> execute:
  source <path>/bin/pylon-setup-env.sh <path>

If you want the environment for the standard installation to be persistent, you 
can add
   source /path/to/your/pylon5/bin/pylon-setup-env.sh /path/to/your/pylon5
to ~/.bashrc

For special use cases, you can do a manual environment setup as follows:

   export PYLON_ROOT=/path/to/your/pylon5

Even though there is currently only one variable needed, using pylon-setup-env.sh
is still the preferred way to set up your environment, as we might add more variables
in the future.
```

I have tried it in so many ways that I would be happy for any help or advices to proceed to use these shared libraries in my own libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this question is old, and I'm surprised it isn't answered yet.

I just got it working, but my project uses Scons as the build system. Still, the issue I found was that it wasn't linking enough libraries. This is what I set to get what I needed (the `qmake` syntax might be off):

```
LIBS += \
  -L/opt/pylon5/lib64 \
  -lpylonbase \
  -lGenApi_gcc_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0 \
  -lGCBase_gcc_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0 \
  -lLog_gcc_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0 \
  -lMathParser_gcc_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0 \
  -lXmlParser_gcc_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0 \
  -lNodeMapData_gcc_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0
```